# Adding another element to a structure

Tags: c, struct

I have the following problem:

I want to add: Role to the structure but I get the following error codes.

**error: initializer element is not constant**

**error: (near initialization for 'resource01.resource.role')**

What am I doing wrong?

```
struct RestResourceNode_S
{
    RestResource_T resource;
    struct RestResourceNode_S const *next;
};

struct RestResourcesManager_S
{
    struct RestResourceNode_S const * resourcesList;
    struct RestResourceNode_S const * cursor;
};

typedef struct RestResourcesManager_S RestResourcesManager_T;




/* Note: Resource handler for "/test" and "test/\*", but not "/test*" */
static char const resource02Url[] = "/test";
static char const resource02Type[] = "type3";
static char const resource02Interface[] = "if3 if4";
static int  resource02Role =2;
static struct RestResourceNode_S resource02 =
{
    {
        resource02Url,
        resource02Type,
        resource02Interface,
        resource02Role,
        &Resc02Handler_call
    },
    &resource01,
};


/home/serval/workspace/posix/examples/RestServerApp_POSIX/src/RestApp/RestResources.c:47: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/serval/workspace/posix/examples/RestServerApp_POSIX/src/RestApp/RestResources.c:47: error: (near initialization for 'resource01.resource.role')
```

Comment: What *is* going wrong?

Comment: /home/serval/workspace/posix/examples/RestServerApp_POSIX/src/RestApp/RestResources.c:47: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/serval/workspace/posix/examples/RestServerApp_POSIX/src/RestApp/RestResources.c:47: error: (near initialization for 'resource01.resource.role'

Comment: Your entire fragment is 34 lines and `resource01.resource.role` is nowhere to be found in it, so where's line 47 and what's wrong with it is a complete mystery.